# create and publish commandline using click

Tags: python, click

I am new to click command. I am trying to write on terminal something like: **hello project template list** which should then call a function to simply read a json file and print the content on the terminal. I have figured out the way to do so using only hello list but I want to know how hello project template list could be done.
I have tried the below code:

```
import click
import json

@click.group()
def cli():
    pass

@cli.command(name='to print something')
def project():
    # click.echo('hello project template list')
    with open('template.json', ) as f:
        data = json.load(f)
        for i in data['project_template']:
            print()
            print("Template name: ", i['template_name'])
            print("GitHub location: ", i['github_location'])
            print("Project Description: ", i['project_description'])
            print()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    cli()
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Are you getting an error?  It might be helpful to post your stack trace. It might also be helpful to provide a sample of `template.json`.